# npm ENOENT error on mac OS X - no such file or directory

Tags: macos, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I get this error trying to install a npm package. Can you please help ?

Thanks

```
$ sudo npm install -g ios-deploy
npm WARN lifecycle ios-deploy@1.9.0~preinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) ios-deploy@1.9.0 ./src/scripts/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ios-deploy-298c9491
npm ERR! Darwin 15.2.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ios-deploy"
npm ERR! node v6.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.2
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/ios-deploy
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/ios-deploy'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/ios-deploy'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/ludovicroux/Documents/PROJETS/BOARDLINE/dev/boardline/npm-debug.log
```

It only works with

```
 sudo npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a problem of running npm under root account, which is discouraged.

To run across all your computer npm without sudo flag anymore, you can install `nvm` -stands for **n**ode **v**ersion **m**anager. It allows you to have many node version as well as installing `--global` packages without using the root account (the sudo command).

You can install their official script to install it:

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.1/install.sh | bash`

- nvm repo: https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Hope it helps.

Comment: ;) ok, I just installed nvm using the script. I still have the ENOENT error with `sudo npm install -g ios-deploy`. But it seems that `npm install -g ios-deploy` is working...

Comment: Are you on OSX El Capitan?

Comment: I'm on OSX 10.11.6 and have no problem at all. But it seems you will need to install it with `npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm=true`. Well that's not a problem and now you have nvm installed so you don't have to mess with permissions anymore when installing global packages.

Comment: should I "undo" this command I did ealier `sudo npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root`?   I just run ionic run ios --device, and the compilation seems ok but I get an error with ios-deploy : 2016-12-01 12:52:54.034 ios-deploy[3496:92928] [ !! ] Unable to locate DeviceSupport directory. This probably means you don't have Xcode installed, you will need to launch the app manually and logging output will not be shown

Comment: Do you also have `ios-sim` installed? Nevertheless, try to run it from Xcode. I always do it this way to avoid problems with other packages. `ionic run ios` and `ionic run ios` never worked good for me (1 year developing under ionic1 and ionic2)

Comment: yes I have ios-sim installed. when I click the play button on xcode it launches the app in the simulator, how can I run it on the device ?

Comment: You just have to select your device instead the simulator. The selector is next to to the PLAY/STOP button

Comment: ok thanks ! now I get a `Could not find Developer Disk Image`

Comment: My friend. I think you have a mismatch between iOS version and Xcode version. Maybe you are trying to build the app on an iPhone with iOS 10 version and your Xcode version is old and do not support it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129538/discussion-between-louis-and-jorge).

Comment: ;) Jorge ! you might be right, I am using Xcode 7.3 and the iphone is on iOS 10 !! ah ! and I have to update the whole OS to be able to update xcode....painful apple...